# How to Make a Custom Base URL with Blazor Server App?

Tags: c#, http, blazor, single-page-application

I am trying to get a custom base url for my Blazor Server app. Instead of "https://localhost:5001/" as the base url, I want to make a custom url such as "https://custom-name/" in Blazor Server application.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is my current code for Program.cs:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddChecklistAppDependencies();
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Through the IIS. But usually when you deploy the Web App to the hosting of your chose you need a reserved domain name like custom-name.net.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/set-custom-domain-name-for-localhost-website-iis